# Possible to write what would be output into a HTML file?

Tags: java, html

What I want to do is make it so that when the program runs it will run the ordinary way but if the user selects that they want the display to be in html then it will run what the ordinary program would do but rather than display it in the console it will write what was going to appear in the console into a html file that the user specifies. Is this possible? I have code to accept the user input and have them specify what format they want it in as well as open the browser but I'm not sure if this could work. The code I have already is below:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class reader {
    static int validresults = 0;
    static int invalidresults = 0;
    // Used to count the number of invalid and valid matches
    
    public static boolean verifyFormat(String[] words) {
        boolean valid = true;

        if (words.length != 4) { 
            valid = false;
        } else if (words[0].isEmpty() || words[0].matches("\\s+")) {
            valid = false;
        } else if ( words[1].isEmpty() || words[1].matches("\\s+")) {
            valid = false;
        }
                
        return valid && isInteger(words[2]) && isInteger(words[3]);}
    
    // Checks to see that the number of items in the file are equal to the four needed and the last 2 are integers
    // Also checks to make sure that there are no results that are just whitespace
    public static boolean isInteger(String input) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Checks to make sure that the data is an integer
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) { // Runs until it is specified to break
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter filename");
            String UserFile = sc.nextLine();
            File file = new File(UserFile);

            if (!file.exists()) {
              continue;
            }

            if (UserFile != null && !UserFile.isEmpty()){ 
                System.out.println("Do you want to generate plain (T)ext or (H)TML");
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(file.toURI());
                } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("T")) {
                      processFile(UserFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Do you want to generate plain (T)ext or (H)TML");
                }
            }
          }
        }
    
    // Checks how the user wants the file to be displayed 
    private static void processFile(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String hteam;
        String ateam;
        int hscore;
        int ascore;
        int totgoals = 0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");
            // Splits the file at colons

            if(verifyFormat(words)) {
                hteam = words[0];       // read the home team
                ateam = words[1];       // read the away team
                hscore = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);       //read the home team score
                totgoals = totgoals + hscore;
                ascore = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);       //read the away team score
                totgoals = totgoals + ascore;
                validresults = validresults + 1;
                
                System.out.println(hteam + " " +  "[" + hscore + "]" +  " " + "|" + " " + ateam + " " + "[" + ascore + "]");   
                // Output the data from the file in the format requested

            }
            else{
                invalidresults = invalidresults + 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total number of goals scored was " + totgoals);
        // Displays the total number of goals
        System.out.println("Valid number of games is " + validresults);
        System.out.println("Invalid number of games is " + invalidresults);

        System.out.println("EOF");
    }
}
```

Comment: So just write an HTML file that holds the results instead of displaying it on the screen?

Comment: How would I do this? The program is going to read a text file and display them in a certain manner, how would I then write this to a html file and have that file opened if the user specifies that they want it in html?

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is where we'll write the HTML to if the user's chooses so
private static final String OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.html";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String content = "Foobar";

    final boolean toHtml;
    String input;

    //Get the user's input
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Do you want messages "
                + "written to (P)lain text, or (H)TML? ");

        input = scanner.nextLine();
    } while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("p") 
            || input.equalsIgnoreCase("h")));

    toHtml = input.equalsIgnoreCase("h");

    if (toHtml)
    {
        //Redirect the standard output stream to the HTML file
        final FileOutputStream fileOut //False indicates we're not appending
                = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILENAME, false);
        final PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(fileOut);

        System.setOut(outStream);
    }

    System.out.println(toHtml 
            ? String.format("<p>%s</p>", content) //Write HTML to file
            : content); //We're not writing to an HTML file: plain text
}
```

Comment: So how does this work? I entered it in the correct manner but when I opened the html file all I got was Foobar

Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename Enter filename rather than the details that were supposed to be written to the file

Comment: @Rajesh - This was an example, not a full coded solution